# Suspend/resume thread?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Is it possible in VB.NET to suspend and resume processes?

I would like to entirely pause a process or an external thread.

Comment: I don't understand your question: do you need to pause an external process or an internal thread within your app?

Comment: Are you talking about VB6 or VB.NET?

Answer (score 2):

**Warning: .Suspend() has been depreciated. The reason is suspending another thread is not even remotely safe.**

*Lets say somewhere on a lower level, there is a thread performing some important operation like writing bytes, now you go ahead and suspend the thread before it finishes what happens to that range of bytes? It will likely be paused until you Resume() which can lead to damaging results.*

with that said:

```
Thread.Sleep(Time in ms)
```

will **pause** the *current* thread for x amount of milliseconds.

If you are looking to **Suspend** the *current* thread then

```
Thread.CurrentThread.Suspend()
```

and to **resume** the *current* thread

```
Thread.CurrentThread.Resume()
```

You will need to import the namespace to use this code as is.

```
Imports System.Threading
```

or change it to

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Suspend()
```

Be careful and if your not Multi-Threading and handling your own threads, I don't recommend it. There is a reason why MS depreciated the code. Keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

This is the right way to do what (I think) you need.
You have to call `ResumeThread()` and `SuspendThread()` (API functions) on all the threads of target process...